# How to use pdb to debug module written by C?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I am using pdb to debug a python program, and the python program uses a module written by C. I want to use "step" command to enter the function in the module written by C, but I find this operation can't be successful. Is there any method to use pdb debug module written by C? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pdb` won't allow you to debug modules written in C. You can however use `gdb` to debug errors you might be encountering in C code.

To launch a Python script using `gdb` you can use the following command:

```
gdb python
```

and then to execute your script:

```
(gdb) run <myscript>.py
```